# Spring MVC : Implementing Cometd channel functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, server-push, cometd

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would like to
  implement chat functionality provided by Cometd. Now, in this
  project, there are various groups each with unique-id(Primary key).
  Whenever a group is created I would like to create a channel and then
  when a member sends a message inside the group, then the message is
  sent through that channel so it goes to the groupMembers only. No
  persistence of chat messages is required,just that messages should be
  pushed to all those who are online.

  - My main motivation behind selecting cometd was as I read there is a
    lot of documentation and help, but as I see, there are hardly good
    examples on net and the documentation on the project website is
    obscured with too much technical details. I have implemented some
    code, but to be honest, I don't know what to do next and where to go
    next.

Here is some of the code I have implemented, kindly have a look.

ChatService.java :

```
package com.journaldev.spring.chat;

import org.cometd.annotation.ServerAnnotationProcessor;
import org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer;
import org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

@Component
@Singleton
public class ChatService{

    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;

    private ServerAnnotationProcessor serverAnnotationProcessor;

    @Inject
    public void setBayeuxServer(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer){
        this.bayeuxServer = bayeuxServer;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.serverAnnotationProcessor = new ServerAnnotationProcessor(bayeuxServer);
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException{
        System.out.println("Configuring Service "+name);
        serverAnnotationProcessor.processDependencies(bean);
        serverAnnotationProcessor.processConfigurations(bean);
        serverAnnotationProcessor.processCallbacks(bean);
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    public void postProcessBeforeDestruction(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        serverAnnotationProcessor.deprocessCallbacks(bean);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BayeuxServer bayeuxServer() {
        // bean.setOption(BayeuxServerImpl.LOG, "3");

        return new BayeuxServerImpl();
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setAttribute(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE, bayeuxServer);
    }

}
```

ChatProducer :

```
public class ChatProducer {

    private ChatService chatService;

    public void setChatService(ChatService chatService){
        this.chatService = chatService;
    }

   public synchronized void sendMessages(String messages){
          // Unfortunately I don't know where to send the messsages and how
   }
}
```

Any help would be nice as to how to create channels, subscribe and send messages over them. If anyone wants to chat for this, kindly post a comment, I will create a chatroom for the same. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: The CometD documentation includes [tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/) for simple cases like yours. Have you read and studied them ?

Comment: @sbordet : I have... Does not fulfil the use-case I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you translate your "group" concept to what in the [tutorial](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/#server_stock_price) is a stock symbol, the use case seems identical to me (if it is not, then you have to detail your question).

Therefore by looking at [example 3.2](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/#d0e601) of the tutorial, you will see how a stock price update is sent to all subscribers interested in changes for that particular stock.

In your case the tutorial example translates to sending a message to all members of a particular group, which is what you asked for.

The tutorial contains code with comments about how to create the channel, initialize it, and use it to send messages to its subscribers.

Give the tutorial a go: build it, run it, study it. Once you have grasped how it works, you will see that your example is similar and very easily implemented.

Once you have the basics functionality you want running, consider adding [authorization](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_java_server_authorization). This will allow you to fine-tune who can post messages to what channel.